# CSS: How to select a tag inside an element?

Tags: html, css, tags, selection

So as my other question failed because I failed to post the right stuff.

My question is if there is a way to chosse tag inside an element... This is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" media="screen"/> 
<mytest>
    <mystory>
        <myItem>
            <myDescription>Hello my name is <myName>Frosta</myName></myDescription>
        </myItem>
        <myItem>
            <myDescription>Hello my name is <myName>Frosti</myName></myDescription>
        </myItem>
    </mystory>
</mytest>
```

this is my css file :

```
myitem{
    color: green
}

myDescription{
    color: blue;
}

myName{
    color: red;
    
}
```

The problem is when I call the tag title or topicWord there's nothing that displays... And I would like to habe the title in blue and the topicWord in red...

What i tried :

```
element element

element+element

element1~element2

element>element
```

and it just dosn't work... It doesn't even show up...

EDIT: fixed a typo in the CSS file but it doesn't change my initial problem...

Comment: `newsItem` element and `newsitem` in CSS don't match (case)

Comment: fixed, thanks but it still deosn't fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say

```
title {
    display: inline;
    color: blue;
}
```

because title element is `display: none;` by default. Note however, that it treats its content as text and shows  explicitly.

Comment: humm okay thanks... is there any possibility on how I could fix the thing that  is displays text to show explicitly?

Comment: Unfortunately not AFAIK. This is due to W3C standards. See https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html

Comment: humm ok thank you very much. Thanks to your help I could get a better understanding of the display parameter and fix 3 other problems! You rock! I will try to fix this last problem that I have.

Comment: Glad to help. Mind upticking my answer and confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code through a jsfiddle, and I see that the title tag is not showing up, but if you remove the topicWord from within the title tag, it shows up fine, and is actually getting the styles changed fine.
Why don't you put your title in an h2 tag, with a class of title? That way, it shows up, and you can do this for your css:

```
.title{color: blue;}
```

Comment: I know that it would word just fine with a title but I'm not allowed to change the xml file unfortunately....